# why space is leaving while adding widgets inside Wrap widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, gesturedetector

I have created a custom widget which is an entirely separate class so while pressing an add more button the custom widget should be added inside Wrap Widget, everything working fine but while adding a custom widget inside the Wrap widget it leaves space on the right side and custom widgets are adding next row. Below I have attached a screenshot where we can see the space a lot of space.
I don't want to leave space like below can anyone help in this case. Thanks in advance.

[image]

this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int count =0;
  List images = [];

  void onCrossSelected(UniqueKey id) {
setState(() {
  print("${id.hashCode}");
  images.removeWhere((element) => element.id.hashCode == id.hashCode);
});
  }
  void addAtInitial() {
    setState(() {
      images.add(ItemButton(
        onCrossSelect: (UniqueKey sId) {
        onCrossSelected(sId);
      },
          id: UniqueKey(),
        initialItem: 0,
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    addAtInitial();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  ...images,
                  Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          images.add(ItemButton(onCrossSelect: (UniqueKey sId) {
                            onCrossSelected(sId);
                          }, id: UniqueKey()));
                        });
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,),
                          ),
                          Text("add more"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),)
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final ItemCallback onCrossSelect;
  final UniqueKey id;
  final int? initialItem;
  const ItemButton({Key? key, required this.onCrossSelect, required this.id, this.initialItem}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemButtonState createState() => _ItemButtonState();
}

typedef ItemCallback = void Function(UniqueKey count);

class _ItemButtonState extends State<ItemButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {

            },
            child: Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 110,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text("${widget.id}",style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 20
              ),)),
            ),
          ),
          widget.initialItem == 0
              ? Container()
              : Positioned(
            top: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              widget.onCrossSelect(widget.id);
              print("${widget.id}");
            },
                child: Icon(Icons.close,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 30,),

          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here where you define an empty container:

```
widget.initialItem == 0
              ? Container()
              : Positioned(
```

If you remove this and keep everything as expected you dont have the space. Since you are using `Wrap` Widget the empty container also acts as child adjacent to the previous child in the main axis, given by direction, leaving spacing space in between.

[image]From the documentation:

> If there is not enough space to fit the child, Wrap creates a new run
> adjacent to the existing children in the cross axis.

removing this line in your code you don't have any empty space as behavior in your UI. [Read more here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

Comment: thanks for the comment I found the solution for the issue you can check my answer Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

So after all using flutter tools, I found the issue is with an empty container

```
widget.initialItem == 0
              ? Container()
              : Positioned()
```

so this container takes the entire width so i just add height = 0, width = 0, now its fine its working upto my expectations

```
widget.initialItem == 0
                  ? Container(height = 0, width = 0)
                  : Positioned()
```